# Internal server error after .htaccess Rewrite rule edit

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error, htdocs

I followed this process to deploy WordPress Multisitehttps://www.siteyaar.com/google-cloud-wordpress-multisite/#comment-2038. When I edit Rewrite rule in .htaccess file and try to visit Admin URL, error is thrown... Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Internal server errors (error 500) are often caused by plugin or theme function conflicts [1], so if you have access to your Dashboard, try deactivating all plugins. If you don’t have access to your admin panel, try manually resetting your plugins [2] (no Dashboard access required).

As the link  [3], the two most common causes of this error are a corrupted .htaccess file and exceeding your server’s PHP memory limit. The .htaccess file in your WordPress directory can become corrupted after you install a plugin or make another change to your WordPress site. All you need to do is create a new .htaccess file.

PHP memory limit issues often occur as the result of a poorly-coded plugin running on your site or a site that’s grown considerably over time and is using too many plugins. You’ll begin to exceed the PHP memory limits set by your hosting provider once either of these things happen. The result is a 500 internal server error.

I hope, link [4] also could be helpful but previous links should help you to find out the reason and to have solution.

If you have enabled stackdriver logging then please check is there have any VM related error, to do troubleshooting about GCP VM please follow the documentation [5].

[1] https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-500-message-when-trying-to-access-wp-admin-dashboard/

[2] https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/

[3] https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-the-500-internal-server-error-on-your-wordpress-website

[4] https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/

[5] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances

Comment: Hello

Thanks for your advice. I had fresh install WordPress multisite click to deploy which had no plugins. Server error is thrown as soon as Rewrite rules are pasted in htaccess file as provided by WordPress Network Admin>>Settings>>Network Setup.
I dont know how to take server error log from google cloud platform.

You may check this step yourself, it does not work.

I would appreciate if you could advise working solution.

Regards

Sanjeev

Comment: If I want to rewrite rules, I will need to work on a domain registered website, unfortunately I don't have this at present.
About to have server error logs you could follow the documentation [1] and [2].
 
[1] https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-logging/latest/index.html
[2] https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/viewing-errors